# Debugging a GEF Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gef

All,

How can we debug a Eclipse plug-in based on GEF? Currently, I have a `Activator` class and custom editor from [Example](http://java-eclipse.info/IBM.Redbooks-Eclipse.Development.using.the.Graphical.Editing.Framework.and.the.Eclipse.Modeling.Framework/7823/DDU0018.html) . Yet I am not able to find any output for the plugin. I tried using the "Launch Eclipse in Debug Mode" and setting a breakpoint in the `Activator` constructor method, but do not find any debugging activities taking place.

Can anyone please guide on how to go about with debugging?

---

Additional info:

Here is the trace I get in the Debug window:

```
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main at localhost:1708   
   Thread [main] (Running) 
   Daemon Thread [State Data Manager] (Running) 
   Daemon Thread [Start Level Event Dispatcher] (Running)   
   Daemon Thread [Framework Event Dispatcher] (Running)  
   Daemon Thread [[Timer] - Main Queue Handler] (Running)   
   Daemon Thread [[ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread] (Running)   
   Thread [Worker-JM] (Running)  
   Daemon Thread [Bundle File Closer] (Running) 
   Thread [Worker-0] (Running)   
   Daemon Thread [Java indexing] (Running)   
   Thread [Worker-1] (Running)   
   Thread [Worker-3] (Running)   
   Thread [Worker-2] (Running)   
   Thread [Worker-4] (Running)   
   Thread [Worker-5] (Running)
```

But I do not find the Step Into etc options enabled. The only options available in the Debug mode are Suspend and Terminate. The process does not stop at the breakpoints I have set.

Here is the MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Project1
Bundle-SymbolicName: mypackage.plugin1;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: mypackage.plugin1.MyPlugin
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.draw2d;bundle-version="3.6.1",
 org.eclipse.gef;bundle-version="3.6.1"
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging GEF plugin should be equal of debugging any Eclipse Plugin. Try to verify that your debugger actually works, and that the debug configuration contains your own plugin.

To check that your plugin is there, you need to go run -> debug configurations... -> plugins. Here you can see what plugins are loaded when you start run or debug.

Also make sure that breakpoint is in start of the Activators start() function, that is basically the entry point for the plugin.